# jQuery ajax call giving status 0 in a mobile solution

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been working on a cross platform mobile solution which is client-server based application. I'm using ajax call to make a web service call to the server. Most of the web services are working fine but when there is some computation that needs to be done at server end based on the request and there is a delay in the response, I'm getting status 0 as response. Tried with timeout option but of no use. 
Adding some same code snippet for your reference.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: wsUrl,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        timeout: 300000,
        data: soapRequest,
        success: processSuccess,
        error: processError
});

function processSuccess(data, status, req)
{
}

function processError(data, status, req) 
{
   console.log(data+'---------   '+status+'-------- '+req);
}
```

Sometimes if the server response is fast, we are getting the expected response but most of the time, we are getting status 0 error. Mostly after 2 mins I'm getting this error. Trying the same code in native android application is working fine without any issues. Will there be any option to make sure that the request doesn't break until the complete response is fetched from the server.
May be I'm wrong but if not will there be any option to set for the turn around time while making a web service call? Since this being a MOBILE BROWSER based application, if the response is taking more than 2 mins, will the browser has an option of canceling the request with a status 0 response. Not even getting error message.
If you require any further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Long ajax connection - is very bad for server perfomance. What about to check the status every time interval? You can use function `setInterval` for making timer. And every time period you check the status of task.